# Inserting into a std::vector at an index via the assignment operator

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm new to C++ and am curious if this is the preferred way of inserting into a std::vector

```
std::vector<Object_I_madeup> myVector;

   void setAt(int x, Object_I_madeup o)
        {
            myVector[x] = o;

        } // set the array location at x  to be o.
```

I ask because I see a lot of things about using `push_back`,or the highly confusing `insert()`. Is this Java-like way valid? I'd much rather do that...

Comment: What do you mean by *insert*? Do you mean *set* the value at that position? Or do you mean *insert* an element at that location displacing the rest of the elements? I find your use of *insert* confusing...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
myVector[x] = o;
```

It is well-defined only if `x < myVector.size()`. Otherwise, it invokes undefined-behavior, because in that case it attempts to access an element out of the bound of the vector.

If you want to make sure that it checks for out-of-bound-access also, then use [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) as:

```
myVector.at(x) = o;
```

Now it will throw `std::out_of_range` exception if `x >= myVector.size()`. So you have to put this code in `try-catch` block! The difference between them is discussed at great detail here.

- [Why is using "vector.at(x)" better than "vector[x]" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172144/why-is-using-vector-atx-better-than-vectorx-in-c)

Comment: Does the `insert` API on vector also makes this out-of-bound-access checks just like `at` API? `insert` API looks unique in the sense that it takes an iterator position parameter in place of an int position parameter. I don't know if I can really create an iterator w.r.t. a position of a vector which will be out of bounds for it.

Answer (score 2):

`myVector[x] = o` does something completely different from using `myVector.push_back(o)` (or using `insert`). Therefore which method is correct depends on what you are trying to do:

- `myVector[x] = o` doesn't insert in the vector, but replaces the element at position `x` with `o`. Therefore the length of the `vector` doesn't change and the value which was previously at position `x` isn't in the `vector` any more. If the length of `myVector` wasn't bigger then `x` this will result in an out of bounds access, leading to undefined behaviour
- `myVector.push_back(o)` will insert `o` at the end of `myVector`. Therefore after this operation the length of the `vector` will be increased by one and the last element of `myVector` will be `o`. No values have been removed from `myVector`.
- `myVector.insert(i, o)` will insert `o` at an arbitrary position, specified by the iterator `i`. Therefore the length of the vector will be increased by one and the `"ith"` element (element number `myVector.begin() - i`) will be `o`

Answer (score 1):

It's only valid if vector's size is at least x+1. If it's not, you're accessing it out of bounds.

If you declare the vector like this:

```
std::vector<Object_I_madeup> myVector(10); // construct the vector with size 10
                                           // and default-initialize its elements
```

then you can safely access indexes 0 - 9.
Your vector in the example is empty, though, there isn't yet a valid index to it.

Comment: In other words, it won't resize the vector for you if the index isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in case you are not trying to access it out of its bounds, i.e. vector size is greater than x.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a java-like equivalent of the `ArrayList.set()` method, you can do it more closely via

```
void setAt(int x, Object_I_madeup o)
{
    myVector.at(x) = o;
}
```

Much like the Java version, `vector::at()` will throw an exception if the vector is not large enough.  Note, this makes a copy of the object (actually, two, since you're also passing by value to the function).