# why is there a Segmentation Fault with the storing of this vector?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a segmentation fault in a seemingly fine code. I know where the fault is occuring but cannot seem to fix it.

```
for(int i=0; i<position.size();i++)
    {
            ordered[position[i]-1]= name[i];
      }
```

this is where the fault it
the code is supposed to read in a file of names with corresponding numbers then sort the names in order of their numbers. 
here is the entire code for reference:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector> 
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_vector(vector<string> ordered){
    for(int i = 0; i < ordered.size(); i++)
            cout << ordered[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
int main() 
{
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("input2.txt");
    string s;
    string word;
    vector<int> position;
    vector<string> name;
    vector<string> ordered;
    string n;
    int p;

    while( !inf.eof())
    {

            getline(inf, s);
            istringstream instr(s);
            instr>>p;
            instr>>n;
            while(!instr.eof()){
                    position.push_back(p);
                    name.push_back(n);
                    instr>>p;
                    instr>>n;
            }

    }
    for(int i=0; i<position.size();i++)
    {
            ordered[position[i]-1]= name[i];


    }
    print_vector(ordered);
    inf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is position[i] is ever 0?

Comment: with the input file, position[0]=1

Comment: Did you actually verify that _all_ of the values in `position` are actually above zero? I don't mean what the values are in the file you are loading but the actual contents of `position`

Comment: here is the fie that is being read in, maybe this will help.

    '9 John 3 Jane 7 Tom 2 Sam 
    6 Tom 1 Nicole 5 Tom 
    4 Jane 8 Ben'

Answer (score 3):

Without compiling and testing my answer, I think in order to use assignment properly with the vector 'ordered' you must make sure that `0 <= position[i]-1 < ordered.size()` is always the case. Because 'ordered' starts out empty, you are attempting to access out-of-bounds. See [this question/ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204206/inserting-into-a-stdvector-at-an-index-via-the-assignment-operator).

Therefore, you might want to consider using another modifier member function such as 'insert' or 'push_back' to avoid the out-of-bounds problem. Although, at the same time, you may want to change how you store the data since you are trying to rely on the index value of the 'ordered' vector to represent some integer key/ value.