# vector of bools not initialized correctly

Tags: c++

I have initialized a `vector` of `bools`, but for some reason 
everything is set to `false`. Why can I not set a `vector` of
`bool` to `true`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<bool> d_WFlag;
  int d_numGrids = 4;
  d_WFlag.resize(d_numGrids);

  d_WFlag[0] = false;
  std::cout << std::noboolalpha << d_WFlag[0] << " == " << std::boolalpha << d_WFlag[0] << std::endl;
  for(int i = 1; i < (d_numGrids - 1); ++i)
  {
    d_WFlag.push_back(true);
    std::cout << std::noboolalpha << d_WFlag[i] << " == " << std::boolalpha << d_WFlag[i] << std::endl;
  }
  d_WFlag[d_numGrids - 1] = false;
  std::cout << std::noboolalpha << d_WFlag[d_numGrids - 1] << " == " << std::boolalpha << d_WFlag[d_numGrids - 1] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to do `d_WFlag.resize(d_numGrids, true);`?

Comment: You need to add some more information here if you want to keep the question open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d_WFlag.push_back(true);` **adds** a *new entry* to the vector, it doesn't *change* any old one! That is, if the vector initially has `N` elements, `d_WFlag.push_back(true);` would make the vector to have `N+1` elements.

If you want to modify an existing element at index `i`, then do this:

```
d_WFlag[i] = true; //it modifies!
```

where `i` must be a valid index, otherwise the above code would invoke undefined behavior.

If you suspect that `i`  may be an invalid index, then you can use `at()`:

```
d_WFlag.at(i) = true;
```

It throws `std::out_of_range` exception when `i` is invalid.

To know when `[]` is better than `at()` and when `at()` is better than `[]`, see this:

- [Why is using "vector.at(x)" better than "vector[x]" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172144/why-is-using-vector-atx-better-than-vectorx-in-c)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a no-brainer, this answer **is correct,** +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can, however what you are doing is looping from 0 to < 3 (2).

On the line `d_WFlag.resize(d_numGrids)` you create a vector that looks like:
`[0] = false, [1] = false, [2] = false, [3] = false`.

Later you iterate from `0 to < 3`. You will enter the loop with the values `[0,1,2]`, all of those values are already initialized to **false**.

In the loop you call ([push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/)) which appends elements to the end of the vector. The first one will be in **d_WFlag[4]**, this element is never printed.

Try setting it with `d_WFlag[i] = true;` instead.

Comment: +1 for showing what happens when using resize().

Answer (score 1):

Only if you read the documentation of `std::vector::push_back()`... It **appends** an element to the end of the vector. So what you do is "add true as the 5th item, then print the first one; add true as the sixth item, then print the second one..." etv.

To change the elements already there, use `operator[]`:

```
d_WFlag[i] = true;
```

And, by the way, the end condition in the `for` loop needs to be `i < dNumGrids`, else you don't set the last item.

Comment: Any reason for revoking the upvote?

Comment: I think someone is trolling here. BTW, +1!

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks! Trolling is not unrare these days, especially by those who don't put effort into their questions then they face my sarcasm as a consequence - and they cannot possibly stand that... Too bad.