# Delimiter extracting out a range of data

Tags: c++, delimiter, getline

From textfile(Range.txt),

```
Range:1:2:3:4:5:6....:n:
```

There's a list of result, but i only need to extract digit 1 2 3 to the last digit, but sometimes the last digit may varies

so i read in the file, extract out the delimiter and push it into a vector.

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("Range.txt");

istringstream range(temp);
getline(range, line,':');

test.push_back(line);
```

How do i capture all the value? I have this and it only capture one digit.

Comment: This could be done with `Boost.Split` or your own split function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have this and it only capture one digit*

You need to use a loop :-

```
while (getline(range, line, ':')) 
  test.push_back(line);
```

Later using the vector you can process it to get the integers only.

Answer (score 0):

Plase, read that: [Parsing and adding string to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161076/parsing-and-adding-string-to-vector/18161151#18161151).

You just have to change the delimiter (from `whitespace` to `:`).

```
std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
std::string line;

if (infile.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Well done! File opened successfully." << std::endl;
    while (std::getline(infile, line, ':'))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::vector<std::string> tokens{std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};

        // Now, tokens vector stores all data.
        // There is an item for each value read from the current line.
    }
}
```