# c++: Iteration of vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector, iteration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string>  a;
    a.push_back("1 1 2 4");
    a.push_back("2 3 3 3");
    a.push_back("2 2 3 5");
    a.push_back("3 3 3 3");
    a.push_back("1 2 3 4");
    for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        for(int j=0;j<a[i].length();j++)
            cout<<a[i].at[j];
    return 0;
}
```

Hi,when I run the code above,there is an error as below:

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Please help me and tell me why,thanks!

Comment: Call `at` with round brackets: `at(j)`

Comment: Or don't use `at` at all.  I've never found a situation where its semantics are appropriate (especially with `std::string`).

Comment: @JamesKanze: With vector, sometime `at()` is useful and is needed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: what is the specific point of semantic on `std::string` that worries you ? I usually recommend using `at()` rather than `[]` to protect against out of bounds aspects.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: [I recommend `at()` only if the container is not being iterated over inside a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172144/why-is-using-vector-atx-better-than-vectorx-in-c).

Comment: @Nawaz: I commented on your answer but I'll reiterate it here because it cannot be too highlighted, I think. *There are 2 hard problems in computer science: caching, naming, and off-by-1 errors*. I prefer the compiler to elide the check if it can be proven to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Nawaz Rarely.  Using `at()` supposes that you are prepared to handle a bounds error, which is not usually the case.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Most implementations of `[]` will protect against out of bounds as well, unless you turn on optimization.  `at()` says that the code in question is prepared to, or should be prepared to handle out of bounds; that it isn't an error, but simply an "exceptional" case.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Using `at()` could also mean that if the index is wrong, log the error along with the contextual information, and exit the process, without going into UB.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes.  If you plan to catch the exception, and do something with it, then by all means, `at` is the solution.  But beware in actual applications.  If a bounds check error is an actual error (violation of a precondition), you don't want to unwind the stack (which may be corrupted); you want to get out of the process executing as little code as possible.  If the internal state is corrupted, even executing a destructor could make things even worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`at` is a function, need to be called with `()` not `[]`

update

```
cout<<a[i].at[j];
//           ^^^
```

to

```
a[i].at(j)
//   ^^^^^
```

To output `string`, you don't need to `cout` each char, just do

```
for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
{
   std::cout << a[i] << "\n";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or if C++11:

```
for(auto const & s : a)
{
   cout << s << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more simpler to use the range-based for statement. For example

```
for ( const std::string &s : a )
{
    for ( char c : s ) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```